# How can i output answers under their respective questions for a QA site?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have the following tables:

1-users

```
username
user_id
full_name
password
location
interests
```

2-question

```
q_content
q_id
q_category
q_user_id(the username of user who asked the question)
```

3-answers

```
a_id
a_content
a_user_id
q_id
```

I am trying to output questions with answers on a single page, but I do not know how to link the questions to their answers. This becomes even harder with multiple answers to one question.

I am using mySql on XAMPP, localhost. Any help is much appreciated.

**Update:**

```
<?php
$output = mysqli_query($link,$sql); 
if (mysqli_num_rows($output) >= 0) { 
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($output)){ 
        echo $row["q_content"]."<br>".$row["a_content"]."<br>"."<br>";
    }
} else{ 
    echo "error" . mysqli_error($link);
} // } -- You had an extra brace here
```

I used the first method and that is my code for output, but it does not display correctly. how do i correct this, having no array created.

Comment: Use a `JOIN` to do it

Answer (score 0):

#### At first you need to select questions.

```
SELECT * FROM question;
```

Note, you must use limit, if question table is too big, to showing page by page.

For example to show second page with 10 per page records, query must looks like:

```
SELECT * FROM question LIMIT 11, 10
```

#### Then you need to select all answers to each question.

```
SELECT * FROM answers WHERE answers.q_id = :question_id
```

To prevent n+1 problem select all answers in one query and parse result with php. Use the following query instead:

```
SELECT * FROM answers WHERE answers.q_id IN :question_ids
```

where `quetion_ids` is ids of questions on current page.

Comment: If you're going to be parsing the answers in PHP anyway, why not use a `JOIN` and get it all at once? What about the asker and answerers as well?

Comment: I have tried implementing your solution but having a two select statements for both tables isn't helping.

Answer (score 0):

Like the other answer mentioned, you could select all questions, then run a query for all answers for each question, but that's pretty inefficient.

In the interest of completing this in a single query, there are two options below:

One option would be to use JOINs and have each answer on its own row, but order it by the question, so PHP (when looping through and displaying), can 
have it skip duplicates.

```
SELECT
    QuestionTbl.content AS `question`,
    QuestionTbl.category,
    AnswerTbl.content AS `answer`,
    AskerTbl.full_name AS `asker`,
    AnswererTbl.full_name AS `answerer`
FROM
    `question` AS QuestionTbl
LEFT JOIN
    `answers` AS AnswerTbl
    ON QuestionTbl.q_id = AnswerTbl.q_id
INNER JOIN
    `users` AS AskerTbl
    ON QuestionTbl.q_user_id = AskerTbl.user_id
INNER JOIN
    `users` AS AnswererTbl
    ON AnswerTbl.a_user_id = AnswererTbl.user_id
ORDER BY
    QuestionTbl.content ASC,
    AnswerTbl.content ASC;
```

The cooresponding PHP code (structure) would be:

```
<?php
// Assuming an associative array stored in $result

$question = NULL;

foreach($result as $row){
    if($question != $row['question']){
        // Display question
        // The question is $row['question']

        // Update question store
        $question = $row['question'];
    }

    // Display answer(s)
}
```

The other option would be to use `GROUP_CONCAT` to get all answers together, but this can get messy. If you're looping already, I would recommend the first, but here it is:

```
SELECT
    QuestionTbl.content AS `question`,
    QuestionTbl.category,
    AskerTbl.full_name,
    GROUP_CONCAT(
        CONCAT(
            AnswerTbl.content,
            '&&',
            AnswererTbl.full_name 
        )
        SEPARATOR '||'
    ) AS `answers`
FROM
    `question` AS QuestionTbl
LEFT JOIN
    `answers` AS AnswerTbl
    ON QuestionTbl.q_id = AnswerTbl.q_id
INNER JOIN
    `users` AS AskerTbl
    ON QuestionTbl.q_user_id = AskerTbl.user_id
INNER JOIN
    `users` AS AnswererTbl
    ON AnswerTbl.a_user_id = AnswererTbl.user_id
GROUP BY
    QuestionTbl.content,
    QuestionTbl.category,
    AskerTbl.full_name
ORDER BY
    QuestionTbl.content ASC,
    AnswerTbl.content ASC;
```

Then the cooresponding PHP structure would be:

```
<?php
// Assuming an associative array stored in $result

foreach($result as $row){
    // Display question
    // The question is $row['question']

    $answers = explode('||', $row['answers]);

    // Loop through
    foreach($answers as $answer) {
        $components = explode('&&', $answer);

        // Display answer
        // The answer is $components[0];
        // The answerer is $components[1];
    }
}
```

Personally, I prefer the first, as I find it cleaner, and the second could cause problems if the specified delimiter for the `GROUP_CONCAT` was in the answer text, so you'd have to filter that.

Comment: $output=mysqli_query($link,$sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($output) >= 0) {
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($output)){
  echo $row["q_content"]."<br>".$row["a_content"]."<br>"."<br>";}}
 
else{    echo "error" . mysqli_error($link);}
 }     i used the first method and that is my code for output, but it does not display correctly. how do i correct this, having no array created.

Comment: I submitted an edit to add this to your question so the code is formatted. What do you mean "it doesn't display correctly"? What is displayed, vs the desired behavior?